# How i get fast data in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a table of message having 100,00,000 or more records how i can run query and get fast data. simple query is `select title,message from messages` please tell me the proper query to retrieve quickly data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Filter your result by some column and place an index on that filter-column, e.g.,

```
SELECT title,message from messages
WHERE `date` > somedate
```

and the according index

```
CREATE INDEX dateIndex ON messages ( `date` );
```

I don't think you want to get all the 10^7 rows, do you?

Answer (score 4):

on such a broad question, the answer can't be really specific - so heres the broad answer:

[set proper indexing colums](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) (`title` and `message` for your example) and use [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html) on your query to see if those indexes are used.

Answer (score 2):

Add an index on columns `title` and `message`.

```
CREATE INDEX title_message_index ON messages (title, message);
```

Comment: i have used index, i want to more fastable.

Comment: Creating an index on the selected values doesn't improve performance in any way.

Answer (score 1):

Using INDEX will greatly help to optimize the sql operation. Check [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html)